# Import site theme to another site collection subsite?

Tags: sharepoint-online, theme

I'm using SharePoint Online 2013.

I exported my site as a template (.wsp), and imported the template to another top-level site collection. The only problem is that the theme/styling did not convert.

My question is how do you import a theme to a subsite? For example, importing/exporting a design package (.wsp) to the root site. How do you transfer/deploy a theme of a subsite or root site from a site collection to another subsite on a different site collection?